# Does every protein starts with Methionine amino acid

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, human-physiology, amino-acids, translation

During process of protein synthesis we need AUG Codon to start translation .As we know this codon codes for Methionine amino acid so can we say that every protein starts with Methionine amino acid ?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, not every protein starts with a methionine. When the methionine is removed, it is called [N-terminal methionine excision](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00018-004-3466-8.pdf). Abstract excerpt below:

> N-terminal methionine excision (NME) is the major proteolytic pathway
>   responsible for the diversity of N-terminal  amino  acids  in 
>   proteins.  Dedicated  NME components have been identified in all
>   organisms, in all compartments  in  which  protein  synthesis  occurs:
>   cytoplasm, plastids and mitochondria. Recent studies have revealed
>   that NME is regulated at various levels and plays an important role in
>   controlling protein turnover. NME is essential  in  Eubacteria  and 
>   lower  eukaryotes  and  is  the target of many natural and synthetic
>   inhibitors. Such inhibitors  have  considerable  potential  for  use 
>   in the  treatment of various human diseases, from cancer to bacterial
>   and parasitic infections.

And from a recent [review](https://currentprotocols.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/cpps.29) focusing on the methionine aminopeptidase enzyme that cleaves the first methionine:

> Protein synthesis is initiated by methionine in eukaryotes and by
>   formylmethionine in prokaryotes. N‐terminal methionine can be
>   co‐translationally cleaved by the enzyme methionine aminopeptidase
>   (MAP). When recombinant proteins are expressed in bacterial and
>   mammalian expression systems, there is a simple universal rule that
>   predicts whether the initiating methionine will be processed by MAP
>   based on the size of the residue adjacent (penultimate) to the
>   N‐methionine.

**Mitochondria** and other organelles also have [different start codons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start_codon). Their alternate start codons are well-characterized (AUA and AUU in humans and mainly - but not exclusively - GUG and UUG in prokaryotes).